# React: How to restrict the no of columns in Spreadsheet component in react

Tags: reactjs, spreadsheet

I am using react-spreadsheet component in my react app.

I have two columns, but when i copy over 3 data a new column gets added in the webpage.
Is there a way to restrict the spreadsheet with just 2 columns ?

**EDIT:**

```
import Spreadsheet from "react-spreadsheet";
import { useState } from "react";
  
export default function Sheet(){
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    [{ value: "Col1" }, { value: "Col2" }],
  ]);
  return(
  <div>
    <h4>SpreadSheet</h4>
    <Spreadsheet data={data} onChange={setData} />
  </div> 
  )
    
};
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Did you find a answer for this question?
I think you can prevent the extends of no of columns by changing the onChange function. In onChange function, you can process the data value to fit the current spreadsheet schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this `handleChangeData` function as onChange function props of `Spreadsheet` component.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const handleChangeData = (val: Matrix<CellBase<string | undefined>>) => {
    const result = [];
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
      const rowResult = [
        { value: val[index][0]?.value },
        { value: val[index][1]?.value },
      ];
      result.push(rowResult);
    });
    setData([...result]);
  };
```